# How to install Adblock Plus on Firefox in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, firefox, adblock

I use Firefox as my primary browser and I would like to do away with all those pesky ads that different sites keep throwing up and waste my time.

I recently refreshed my browser and I lost my previously installed Adblock Plus. It seems that the last updated version of Adblock plus present on the Ubuntu Apps Directory is compatible with Ubuntu 10.04.

How to reinstall it? Is there any similar such app that can be used on 14.04?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will suggest you to install `uBlock` instead of `ABP` because:

[uBlock vs. ABP: efficiency compared](https://github.com/chrisaljoudi/uBlock/wiki/uBlock-vs.-ABP:-efficiency-compared)

`uBlock` can be installed using [uBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/) link

`ABP` can be installed using [ABP](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) link

Comment: Yeah, still both `uBlock` and `uBlock origin` are better compared to `ABP`.

Comment: I like this idea. Works smooth indeed. Thanks for updating me.

Comment: the ublock link is broken.

Comment: @Fzs2 link updated

Answer (score 7):

Simply install the Adblock Plus addon for Firefox.

Open [this URL](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) in your Firefox and click <kbd>Add to Firefox</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 4):

- Open Firefox
- Open **Add-ons**
- Click **Get Add-ons**
- Type Adblock Plus in search field
- Select **Adblock Plus**
- Click **Install**

[image: ims]
<sub>(source: [go-remove-malware.com](http://www.go-remove-malware.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/firefox-menu.png))</sub>

[image: ims]
<sub>(source: [whstatic.com](http://pad2.whstatic.com/images/thumb/e/ed/Remove-Ads-from-Mozilla-Firefox-Using-Adblock-Plus-Step-1-Version-3.jpg/670px-Remove-Ads-from-Mozilla-Firefox-Using-Adblock-Plus-Step-1-Version-3.jpg))</sub>

**Alternative : You also may use [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/).

uBlock has more customization capabilities and [uses less system resources](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock#performance).**

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

I would install ghostery for even more privacy with adblock.  Less tracking and I noticed that webpages are loading quicker https://www.ghostery.com/en/